# Do you need to finalize a failed prepared statement?

Tags: sqlite

When using `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, do you need to call `sqlite3_finalize` in every path, or only when it succeeds?  For example, here's the code I'm using in a Swift method:

```
let prepare = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db!, SQLString, -1, &delete, nil)
if (prepare == SQLITE_OK){
    if !(sqlite3_step(delete) == SQLITE_DONE){
        sqlite3_finalize(delete) // *
        sqlite3_close(db)
        return
    }
} else {
    // **
    sqlite3_close(db)
    return
}
sqlite3_finalize(delete)
sqlite3_close(db)

// rest of method continues if it didn't fail
```

* I assume I need to call it here, since the statement was successfully prepared even if it didn't successfully run

** But do I need to call it here?

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html

Comment: I saw that, I just wasn't clear on whether "must finalize every prepared statement" included ones that weren't successfully prepared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to call `sqlite3_finalize` if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails.

See [here](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html):

> *ppStmt is left pointing to a compiled prepared statement that can be executed using sqlite3_step(). If there is an error, ***ppStmt is set to
>   NULL**.

Calling `sqlite3_finalize` with NULL does no harm, though.

See [here](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html):

> Invoking sqlite3_finalize() on a NULL pointer is a harmless no-op.